# Index Match with multiple criterias results in 101 but different result with F9

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I hope to find some assistens here, I am loosing my mind. I have following formula:
`{=INDEX(ShipContainer,MATCH([SalesOrderId]&[ContainerNumber],ShipContainer[SalesOrderId]&ShipContainer[ContainerNumber],0),3)}`
The reuslt after CNTR+SHIFT+ENTER is 101 thru the entire table which is not the proper result. But if press F2 followed by F9 it shows me the proper result for that column. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Make sure your calculation mode is **automatic**

Comment: @Gary's Student What do you mean with **automatic**?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I found out what you mean with automatic. It is in automatic mode.

Comment: Are you using *VBA* to enter the formulas or are you entering them manually??

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. The lookup value in match section has to contain the "@". The final formula looks like `{=INDEX(ShipContainer,MATCH([@SalesOrderId]&[@ContainerNumber],ShipContainer[SalesOrderId]&ShipContainer[ContainerNumber],0),3)}`